# internationalized regular expression in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, unicode

How can write regular expressions to match names like 'José' in postgres.. In other words I need to setup a constraint to check that only valid names are entered, but want to allow unicode characters also.

[Regular expressions, unicode style](http://www.siao2.com/2005/04/23/411106.aspx) have some reference on this. But, it seems I can't write it in postgres.

If it is not possible to write a regex for this, will it be sufficient to check only on client side using javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't support character classes based on the Unicode Character Database like .NET does. You get the more-standard `[[:alpha:]]` character class, but this is locale-dependent and probably won't cover it.

You may be able to get away with just blacklisting the ASCII characters you don't want, and allowing all non-ASCII characters. eg something like

```
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]+
```

(JavaScript doesn't have non-ASCII character classes either. Or even `[[:alpha:]]`.)

For example, given `v_text` as a text variable to be sanitzed:

```
-- Allow internationalized text characters and remove undesired characters
v_text = regexp_replace( lower(trim(v_text)), '[!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?\[\\\]\^_\|~]+', '', 'g' );
```

Comment: That regular expression will disallow the `'` character, which is a pretty common one in names.

Comment: This remains true as of Pg 9.3, but if you're reading this and using a newer version, check the manual. It may change in future.