# PostgreSQL regexp - any language

Tags: regex, postgresql

This

```
  Check Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "checks".* FROM "checks" WHERE (title ~* '[p{L}]+' and state @@ 'saved')
```

matches only english characters, but how can I catch any language characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this functionality is not available in PostgreSQL. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820034/internationalized-regular-expression-in-postgresql#answer-3820313) seems to agree. It's 3ish years old, so something may have changed since then, but if it has I'm not aware of it.

From the original poster:

> PostgreSQL doesn't support character classes based on the Unicode Character Database like .NET does. You get the more-standard [[:alpha:]] character class, but this is locale-dependent and probably won't cover it.
>
> You may be able to get away with just blacklisting the ASCII characters you don't want, and allowing all non-ASCII characters. eg something like
>
> ```
> [^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]+
> ```
>
> (JavaScript doesn't have non-ASCII character classes either. Or even [[:alpha:]].)
>
> For example, given v_text as a text variable to be sanitzed:
>
> ```
> -- Allow internationalized text characters and remove undesired characters
> v_text = regexp_replace( lower(trim(v_text)), '[!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?\[\\\]\^_\|~]+'
> ```

**EDIT**: Please also note @depesz answer below. It is possible to get `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` character classes working on Postgres in Linux because Linux's ctype implementation (appears to be) based on UTF-8. I'm not sure if this is an "out of the box" configuration or some kind of upgrade, but good to know it's possible.

Comment: Unicode regex support was improved greatly in 9.1 (I think) - but I don't think extended classes like those you refer to were added. Pg mostly uses operating system support for charsets and locales, making it somewhat subject to the whims of the OS vendors.

Comment: "Unicode regex support was improved greatly in 9.1 (I think)" -- Great to know! My experience with locales, etc. has been the same as you describe, though. At some point, it would be great if that would change, but hard to complain about the quality of great software like PostgreSQL. :)

Comment: A big wishlist item for PostgreSQL is to convert locale and encoding handling over to use the ICU library (http://ICU-project.org). It'd be a giant job and there are some performance concerns, but it'd get rid of some icky platform-specific locale behaviour (Mac OS X's broken collations for many locales, different locale naming on Windows, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I have written an extension that integrates PCRE into PostgreSQL: https://github.com/petere/pgpcre.  It has better support for Unicode properties.  You can write something like

```
title ~ pcre '^\p{L}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use normal classes - [:lower:] and [:upper:] ? Check this:

```
$ select w, w ~ '^[[:lower:][:upper:]]+$' from ( values ( 'aBc'::text ), ('żÓŁW'), ('123')) as x (w);
  w   | ?column?
------+----------
 aBc  | t
 żÓŁW | t
 123  | f
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried the OP's regex to see if it works on your system? In PostgreSQL, much of the locale behavior (which the regex engine stands on) is handled by the OS layer. I'd be surprised if the `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` named character classes worked and `[p{L}]` didn't. For this reason, I suspect that on your system, those character classes work because your OS handles those character classes in a sane way, so `[p{L}]` will work too. If that's the case, this solution won't work for OP, unless he can switch to the platform you're standing on (or one like it).

Comment: Why should it work? PostgreSQL regexps do not contain anything like [p{...}]. Not sure where he found such syntax, but neither perl nor Pg supports something like this. Or, to be exact - it does. [p{L}] is simple character range with 4 characters: p, {, L and }.

Comment: Derp. You're right. However, per [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html): "These [standard character classes] stand for the character classes defined in ctype. A locale can provide others." The (good!) approach you've listed is still platform (that is, `ctype` implementation) specific. What platform are you on where that Postgres regex is giving that behavior? That information could be useful to OP.

Comment: standard linux, with utf8 encoding and en_US.UTF-8 ctype (the letters that I tested it on are from Polish alphabet, so you don't really have to have matching ctype. I think it works because it's all on utf8.